# Pass array from ajax to python (Tornado)

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, web, tornado

I have the following AJAX post.
I'm using the framework Tornado and I don't know how to send the information of the bidimensional array 'point' to the server in order to make some operations with the elements of the array, and then send the result back to the client.

```
$.ajax(
{        
    type: "POST",
    url: "application/json",
    data: {point:point},
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, response)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    statusCode: {
        401: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your get handler in tornado you can do either:

```
data = json.loads(urllib.unquote_plus(self.request.body))
```

or you can do this:

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

Both of these will json decode the body of request in tornado